# Excluding weekends from data in Oracle SQL (EDW/Teradata)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to pull three days in December which are the 11,12 and 15, i don't want data from the 13th and 14th. Any way I could do this without having "write-Access" to SET DATEs.

Here is my query that is not working.

```
select distinct  fill_sold_dt,sum(fill_qty_dspn) as Pills, sum((fill_qty_dspn)/(pkg_sz*pkg_qty) ) as Packs 
 from
prdedwvwh.prescription_fill_sold pf, prdedwvwh.location_store_address_cur lsa, prdedwvwh.drug_cur d
where pf.str_nbr=lsa.str_nbr and
d.drug_id=pf.drug_id
and ((fill_sold_dt(dw,'2014-12-09') + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (5, 6)
 and wic_nbr in (683378,335776,418723)
 group by fill_sold_dt
```

Comment: This does not look like oracle SQL.  Is it SQL-Server?

Comment: It's Teradata/EDW, when we get errors they are always Oracle Errors so I assumed it was Oracle. Maybe PL SQL? Everyone at the office just calls it Teradata.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a condition like this (your_date is a date type):

```
.. where to_char(your_date,'d','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') not in (1,7);
```

This give you all days except weekends.

Without NLS_SETTINGS:

```
.. where  TRUNC (your_date) - TRUNC (your_date, 'IW') + 1 not in (1,7);
```

Comment: Will this work if I don't have "Write ACcess" to SqL? I'm a read access only user.

Comment: I think it should works, but i recommend you use the second case (Without nls_settings) that is more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't completely dechiper the SQL Server query, here is a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4fe46/1) example that shows the similar construct:

```
create table test1 ( fill_sold_dt date, stuff number(10) );
insert into  test1 values('11-DEC-2014',1);
insert into test1 values('12-DEC-2014',2);
insert into  test1 values('13-DEC-2014',3);
insert into  test1 values('14-DEC-2014',4);
insert into  test1 values('15-DEC-2014',5);
insert into  test1 values('16-DEC-2014',6);

select * 
from test1
where to_char(fill_sold_dt,'DY') not in ('SAT','SUN');
```

Comment: I suggest you include nls_settings, because language could affect your solution

Comment: Correct, this was just dummy data to insert into SQLFiddle.

Comment: I think he does not only refer to you INSERT but also to the TO_CHAR() in the solution. With other Language environment you may get SA and SO instead of SAT and SUN ;-)